# Automatic parsing of data in Python

Tags: python, io, readline, readlines

I am wondering if there is a package/function dedicated to the automatic guessing the file structure, e.g. `.csv` file, space or tab delimited etc.

What I'm thinking is to automatically infer `character delimiter` (e.g. tab, space, comma), `header` (yes/no), `quote` (yes/no), `number of lines to skips`, and `comment.char`.

Surely this would mean one extra pass through the file, but if it can guarantee that it will infer correctly it would be nice.

Has there been any attempt?

Comment: Closer/Downvoter: How is this not a programming question?

Comment: How broad is this? I mean, should it recognize all csv types, or csv + excel spreadsheets? word docs? mp3s? late 90s .xm modfiles? it would help focus the question.

Comment: Maybe as a start the requirements listed in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually started working on this, and created the package `pyread` (`pip install pyread`, depends on `pandas`).

Can be used as such:

```
from pyread import read_auto
read_auto(PATHFILE)
```

**The basic functionality now includes all the things mentioned in the original question.**

Two ways to use it:

1) Just load in the data: `read_auto(PATHFILE)`

2) Only if speed matters: infer the file structure and print it as a dictionary so it will be loadable immediately the next time, e.g.:

```
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv
# this will be printed as dict to screen
read_auto(PATHFILE, inferOnly=True) 
{'filepath_or_buffer': PATHFILE, 'skiprows':1, 'sep':',', 'quotechar':'"'}

# Copy and paste the dictionary info into the file, e.g. store it in "info"
info = {'filepath_or_buffer': PATHFILE, 'skiprows':1, 'sep':',', 'quotechar':'"'}
read_csv(**info)
```

This way, it will only have to be inferred once and will thus be roughly 2x faster.

I guess if people would like other features that would be really useful, let me know in the comments and I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Try the csv module, its support not just csv files as the name implies.
But you will have to set the delimiter though

http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: -1 The idea is that it figures out everything automatically.

Comment: @PascalvKooten in that case we will have to wait for a better answer.

Comment: Actually, the `csv` module _can_ already sort of do this, if you are limited to csv files. Look at the `Sniffer` example on the referenced page.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Thanks, I had not seen it. It is still quite limited though (does not skip initial comments), and it needs a wrapper such as `read_auto`. Either way, it is good for inspiration. Thank you